# Returning undefined using the .parentElement method in js

Tags: javascript

I don't know why i'm getting undefined result in my chrome console when i try to get the parentElement Object using the .parentElement method.

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Please include your code in this post, rather than as an image.

Comment: Is your IIFE running after the elements exist? Note that if you use IE/Edge you need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) - but since you are not using IE then it should work if you place the code before the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelector/querySelectorAll returns a NodeList. Which is an Array like object but not an exact array. Simply, you can not call forEach on NodeList. Instead, you can cast NodeList to Array by wrapping it with `Array.from(YourNodeListObject)`  or old school style - `[].slice.call(YourNodeListObject)`. Possibly you've confused it with jQuery's `each` method which can be passed to every array like object.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sales_product_add_button')).forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    alert(evt.target.parentElement.innerText);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class='product' id='product-1'><p>Product-1</p><a class="sales_product_add_button">Click me</a></div>
<hr>
<div class='product' id='product-2'><p>Product-2</p><a class="sales_product_add_button">Click me</a></div>
<hr>
<div class='product' id='product-3'><p>Product-3</p><a class="sales_product_add_button">Click me</a></div>
<hr>
<div class='product' id='product-4'><p>Product-4</p><a class="sales_product_add_button">Click me</a></div>
```